# memtest86+ fails to launch

Tags: memtest

Installed on Ubuntu 12.04, so version is 4.20-1.1ubuntu1 as per repository. Selecting memtest86+ from the GRUB menu gives a black screen for a bit, and then the laptop reboots, failing to show memtest86+ blue screen.

What could be the cause of this and how can I run memtest86+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got memtest86+ from the official website instead and followed instructions on how to make a USB stick (http://forum.canardpc.com/threads/28875-Linux-HOWTO-Boot-Memtest-on-USB-Drive), and that version worked.

For some reason, Ubuntu's version on this particilar AcerAspire 5740 laptop was failing to work.

Answer (score 0):

The fact the memtest86+ doesn't run makes me think that either it did not install properly, or something may have messed with the grub and prevents memtest from running properly. Nevertheless, you can easily run memtest86+ from a flash drive. I believe that even a flash drive with ubuntu will have a memtest option.

Comment: Gave that ago, but same result. I select 'check memory', it shows a black screen for a second or two and then restarts.

Going to try the .ISO from the memtest86+ website.