# Execute memtest86+ on a Ubuntu 16 system

Tags: grub2, usb, memtest

I'm desperately trying to get memtest86+ to work on my fresh Ubuntu 16 LTS install.

I'm aware that there already are questions related to Ubuntu + memtest on this site, but none of the associated solutions work for me:

- [Memtest86+ fails to launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276312/memtest86-fails-to-launch)
- [Memtest86+ options are missing in Grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312304/memtest86-options-are-missing-in-grub-menu?newreg=50c801c106184749ab38b8f31f3302e1)

I started with the creation of a bootable USB flash drive using the auto-installer from [their official website](http://www.memtest.org/). But although the bios menu shows the flash drive in the possible bootable devices, the computer seems not to recognize it and bypasses it, prompting Ubuntu.

Since the auto-installer is only windows-compatible, does the resulting USB stick only work on Windows? Seems really unlikely to me since the OS is not yet started at the stage when this fails.

By searching a bit on the internet, I realized memtest86+ was always installed on all recent Ubuntu distributions. However I can't get it to launch properly.

The memtest options did not show up on the Grub menu. I tried to use **grub-customizer**, a software proposed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312304/memtest86-options-are-missing-in-grub-menu?newreg=50c801c106184749ab38b8f31f3302e1). I managed to add the memtest options to the grub menu but I must have done those incorrectly: when selected, the computer just reboots silently.

I also tried to launch manually the memtest bin file in any way I know to no avail. I notably tried to start it from the grub command line but I don't know how this can be done.

The following is the configuration I use in **grub-customizer** for my main memtest entry:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 6f124093-a471-4959-8a59-b03c11ad2634
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6f124093-a471-4959-8a59-b03c11ad2634
fi
linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

It is identical to the one found in the referenced question save for the weird final numbers at the end of the `search` command - those were generated automatically by the software when choosing an entry template, I decided to leave those as-is.

I don't think memtest was installed improperly since it was shipped natively with Ubuntu. So to me it's really a question of how to use it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your system UEFI?  You may want to look at MemTest86's site for how to boot it:  http://www.memtest86.com/technical.htm

Comment: Yes my system uses UEFI and not BIOS. I tried your method. I extracted the archive on my system and followed their instructions but this command fails: `sudo dd if=$USB_GPT_FREE_FILE.img of=/media/tony/MULTIBOOT` with the error `dd: failed to open '.img': No such file or directory`. When specifying a direct path to the **img** file I have `dd: failed to open '/media/tony/MULTIBOOT/': Is a directory`.

Comment: I also tried `sudo dd if=memtest86-usb.img of=/media/tony/MULTIBOOT/memtest86-usb.img` but the file is just copied over to the USB key and it is not recognized as bootable by UEFI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it appears memtest86+ was not the way to go for UEFI systems. What you want is memtest86, without the **+**.

- **memtest86+** is available on [this website](http://www.memtest.org/). For reasons I can't explain, you can't make a bootable USB device out of its windows installer, that works on UEFI.
- **memtest86** is available on [this website](http://www.memtest86.com/). Creating an USB device bootable on UEFI is possible with this version.

It was just a matter of turning to the right version of this software. Thanks to @Terrance for putting me on the right track with the UEFI / BIOS distinction.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but it still comes up in searches, so I'm going to give a solution.

Most distros supply memtest86+. It is not compatible with UEFI, because UEFI does not support 16 bit . However, PassMark Memtest86 (ver. 5 or later) supports UEFI.

First, obtain the memtest files. Download the USB boot image. http://memtest86.com/download.htm Next, extract the files from the image. I burned the image to a flash drive to facilitate installing on multiple computers.

Second, install memtest86. I made a 500MB partition at the end of my HDD, and formatted to FAT32. Then copied all files from flash drive to this partition. Note: it is possible to install to your EFI directory, but files need to be renamed to avoid overwriting existing boot files.

Third, configure grub2-efi menu entry. There are many ways to add an entry, but the safest way that survives update-grub follows. Using root privileges create file /etc/grub.d/39_memtest, and set it executable. (Note: changing the number in the file name changes the position it appears in the grub menu. DO NOT make it lower than 6 to insure that header and theme run first)

Next make the contents of the file:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Adding Memtest86" >&2

exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Memtest86" {

chainloader (hdx,y)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi

}

EOF
```

*Replace (hdx,y) with your appropriate HDD and partition information.

Then run update-grub You should now have a menu entry that boots into Memtest86