# Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 Random Reboot because of VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualbox, mysql, 17.04

Working on Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 (Host) with VirtualBox.
Using Ubuntu Server 16.04 on each VM (Guest) as WebServer.

Trying to `cp -r /var/www` content to a specific shared folder `wwwfiles` to Host.

Working on Guest after a random period of time the host stops to responding (freezes processes, terminal, Mouse and Keyboard interaction) and reboots by itself. This happens as well without working on both of them (host/guest).

Can't get into error logs `cd /var/log/syslog` (because of sporadically reboots/interruption) on host as on guest.

Looking and reading around is that What I did until now (in command line):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock/*

sudo apt-get update
```

none of these has worked.

My Intent is to:

- Get all data (related mysql of-and running WebBased Applications as Website Data) into a USB Stick to install on a fresh system (supposed corrupted maybe because of a conflict with VirtualBox).

**UPDATE: 07.09.2017**

couldn't leave the problem there so started to work on.
It seems it's more a fileSystem issue.
Executing `fsck -nf /dev/sda1`as root I got following error list:

`Inode [number] was part of orphaned inode list. IGNORED`
*made all passes*
`structure`
`connectivity`
`counts`
`summary information`
It's in fact a FileSystem Error... due I get the message after the check:
`/dev/sda1 ******** WARNING: Filesystem still has error ********`
Not a Hardware as thought.

Comment: IF you boot the host from live media does it still reboot randomly or can you then access the content of  /var/log/syslog which is a file on your host not a directory.

Comment: @ElderGeek yes, I have access to empty content of `/var/log/syslog` (seems is not recording syslogs). Indeed misspelling, not directory but file, my fault. Booting the host normally, and after I try to work on guest, it freezes completely as described. Example... i try to copy the whole `/var/www` content on `media/sf_wwwfiles`. Running the command `cp -r /var/www /media/sf_wwwfiles`starts the copy process, but get stuck in the middle of the process and reboots (Blackscreen and manufacture Logo).

Comment: is this empty `/var/log/syslog` from the live media or from your host system disk which appears to be located at `/media/sf_wwwfiles/var/log/syslog` if I'm understanding you properly. Based on your `cp` command I'm not. Could you please [edit] your post to clarify? Thank you for hel;ping us help you.

Comment: the `/var/log/syslog`on host is empty (can't for interruption reason on guest). Something is not running the way it should obviously. I noticed right now looking to the very fast startup of machine a volume/sda1 issue... and seriously start thinking that HDD could be broken in some partitions. This would in a way explain the randomly boot of machine (working on it or not, didn't matter). Guess I'm forced to make a file recovery of HDD to another machine. Hopefully I'll be able to backup all stored files.

Comment: I had a suspicion that this was a hardware or file system issue. You might find this useful for checking the physical drive on the [host:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077)  It would also be prudent to check the filesystem as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/953293/225694)  as well as run a [memtest on the host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833937/execute-memtest86-on-a-ubuntu-16-system

Comment: Thanks for your message @ElderGeek. I will consider your suggestion and thanks for your links. Will have a look on it in next coming days and why not... Provide an as detailed as possible answer of issue.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent plan.

Comment: I couldn't leave the problem there so starte to work on... It's seems it's more a fileSystem issue... Executing `fsck -nf /dev/sda1`as root I got following error list: `Inode [number] was part of ophaned inode list. IGNORED`made all passes (structure, connectivity, counts summary information). It's in fact a FileSystem Error... not a Hardware. Was wrong, I guess!

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your post as comments can be deleted for numerous reasons and not everyone reads them all. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I don't think it surprising to find a file system error on a system that's been rebooting sporadically. It might be the root cause, but could also be a symptom. I would still do the other tests as well.

Comment: May you provide some suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65250/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-gianni).

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by insuring that the foundation is sound by booting from [verified good](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-17-04/503788) live media . Check the [SMART status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077) of the host drive and run a [memtest.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833937/execute-memtest86-on-a-ubuntu-16-system)

The reason we do the above first is that if the hardware is malfunctioning any repairs we attempt on the filesystem using the same hardware are likely to fail and can't be trusted.

If no errors are found proceed to actually repair the filesystem in question. The fsck command you ran reports the errors but doesn;t actually make any attempt to repair the filesystem. The orphaned inode mentioned is explained well [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290116/what-is-an-orphaned-inode)

I would then manually run fsck repairs on the filesystem with the command `sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1` as based on your question /dev/sda1 is the partition that you are having difficulty with (if it's a different block device, adjust that accordingly.

If you are able to accomplish all this without the system rebooting when booted from live media, but still have the same issue when booted from /dev/sda1 [edit] the results into your post, drop me a comment and I'll expand and revise this answer as necessary.

Sources:

Experience.